# how to apply correct html anchors

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'd like to get some tips on how to achieve this: I created a web page out of this free template: [freehtml5.co - Fitness](https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=fitness-free-website-template-using-bootstrap-3)

My plan is to have on the "Home" page 7 pictures each with a link to the "Schedule" page. When I click picture X, it should take me to the Schedule page and have the Sunday selected and displayed (that's the default). But when clicking picture Y on Home it should take me there and select/display Monday. 
I implemented this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4vaxE/

```js
$('#showdiv1').hover(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').hover(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});

$('#showdiv3').hover(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
});

$('#showdiv4').hover(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div4').show();
});
```

```css
.button {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    display:none;
}
#div1 {
    background:red;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#div2 {
    background:blue;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#div3 {
    background:orange;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#div4 {
    background:green;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
a {
    color:aqua;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1.0);
}
a:hover {
    color:red;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.0);
}
a.buttondefault {
    display:cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<a class="buttondefault" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>

<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>

<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>

<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>

</div>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

however linking from another page to a specific div used in the code is not that straightforward for me.
Thx

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get an answer, please improve your question based on the guide lines listed on the [ask] page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this demonstration i have put together may help you.

Here we have 3 links (pictures in your case). Clicking a link, scrolls to the schedules section of the page and clicks on the relevant day. We use the jquery `trigger` method

```js
// when the link (or in your cash picture link) is clicked
$('.schedule_links .btn').click(function() {
  // get the data attribute for the schedule day we want to click.
  day = $(this).data('schedule_link');
  // trigger the click event on the relevant schedule button.
  $('#' + day).trigger('click');
})



// This bit is already being handled by your template, just here to demonstrate:

$('.schedule_link').click(function() {
  $('.schedule_link').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  day = "#schedule_" + $(this).attr('id');
  $('.schedule').hide();
  $(day).show();
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.schedule {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedule_links">
  <a class="btn" href="#schedules" data-schedule_link="monday">Link 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#schedules" data-schedule_link="tuesday">Link 2</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#schedules" data-schedule_link="wednesday">Link 3</a>
</div>
<!-- spacer to simulate the schedules not being in view when links are clicked. -->
<div class="spacer" style="height:20vh;"></div>

<div id="schedules">
  <a class="btn schedule_link" id="monday" href="#">Monday</a>
  <a class="btn schedule_link" id="tuesday" href="#">Tuesday</a>
  <a class="btn schedule_link" id="wednesday" href="#">Wednesday</a>

  <div class="schedule" id="schedule_monday">
    This is mondays schedule
  </div>

  <div class="schedule" id="schedule_tuesday">
    This is tuesdays schedule
  </div>

  <div class="schedule" id="schedule_wednesday">
    This is wednesdays schedule
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/f2uppL7q/1/

Comment: Hi Brad, few words for you: you are world-class!! Thanks a lot. Didn't know whether I put it across understandable.

Comment: Wow, best compliment ever. Thanks - I'm glad I was able to help.